# Monitoring available wifi SSID / cellular networks with iOS 7 SDK?

Tags: ios7, sdk, ios7.1

Does anyone know whether any API to monitor available :
- WIFI connections / intensity  (nice to have)
- Cellular networks
is available within iOS 7 / 7+ SDK?

Many thanks.

[Edit]

I have tried to use Reachability however I understand it only lets me know whether I am connected to a WIFI network BUT not which WIFI are potentially available.

I used the code below but I can't make it work anymore with iOS7:

```
NSArray *ifs = (id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    NSLog(@"%s: Supported interfaces: %@", __func__, ifs);
    id info = nil;
    for (NSString *ifnam in ifs) {
        info = (id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((CFStringRef)ifnam);
        NSLog(@"%s: %@ => %@", __func__, ifnam, info);
        if (info && [info count]) {
            break;
        }
        [info release];
    }
    [ifs release];
    return [info autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

See [referece](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(status == NotReachable) 
{
//No internet
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
//WiFi
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
//3G
}
```

Try this update on device:

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetwork.h>

+ (NSString *)currentWifiSSID {
// Does not work on the simulator.
NSString *ssid = nil;
NSArray *ifs = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
for (NSString *ifnam in ifs) {
    NSDictionary *info = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)ifnam);
    if (info[@"SSID"]) {
        ssid = info[@"SSID"];
    }
}
return ssid;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt answer. However I understand Reachability only lets me know details regarding a network I AM connected to and not details regarding networks i COULD connect to?

Comment: Thanks for the solution, asking for the ssid is not private? and AppStore save?